# Ubuntu Will Not Read External Hard Drive

Tags: gparted, usb-drive, external-hdd

I have a Seagate External Hard Drive. When I plug it into my laptop Noting happens. If I open Gparted to see if Ubuntu is even seeing the drive there is a little "!" icon with a notice that says:
[image]

Comment: Was this drive plugged into a Windows 8 or 10 system. The error message is typical of partitions left mounted. Either because Windows was hibernated or newer Windows fast start up left on which is always hibernated. Or incorrectly removed from another system. So either mount with Windows and make sure hibernation is off, or run chkdsk from Windows. You may be able to force mount in read only mode -ro or force delete of hiber file. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: As stated by oldfred, a common cause is not shutting down windows properly (Start -> Shutdown) which leaves the NTFS file system in an inconsistent state.  When this happens and you are booting Windows, Windows will run "chkdsk /f" on the drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Comment: I tried that already. All I got was "ntfs-3g is already the newest version."